# Angularfire : How to perform some operations on data before updating template

Tags: java, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to modify some data before its appended to the template.

Assume I have the following :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
  template: `
  <section>
    <article *ngFor="let item of items | async">
       {{ item | json }}
    </article>
  </section>
  `,
})

export class ContactComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('items');
  }
}
```

How do I process each item before its appended to the template.

In Java this would be something like  :

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot d) {
       //here
       ref.child(d.key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              //then update template from here.        
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
       }); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: let temp= db.list('items');    this.items = doSomething(temp);

Comment: @Vega can you expand this in an answer.

Comment: Your question is how to add a listener to each item data change or how modify each item data before it's rendered?

Answer (score 2):

Your data is an observable and is rendered asynchronously.

To modify it you can use a pipe:

```
<article *ngFor="let item of items | async | myCustomPipe"><article>
```

myCustomPipe:

```
export class MyCustomPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], args?: any): any {
    //do your modifications here
    return items;
  }

}
```

---

Or subscribe to the observable and do the async part yourself:

```
public items: any[];

constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  db.list('items').subscribe(items => this.items = this.modifyItems(items));
}

private modifyItems(items: any[]){
  //do your modifications here
  return items;
}
```